# How to create a generic XSLT to add nodes

Tags: templates, generics, select, xslt, nodes

I have an multiple XML files in various formats, all of which need to have a specific tag before it is passed through, hence I want to write a generic XSLT that will take any XML input and simply add the additional tags before and after the payload. For example:

Input XML (example1)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Order>
    <data1>
        <test>1</test>
        <test2>2</test2>
        <test3>3</test3>
    </data1>
</Order>
```

It can also be another XML with `<Invoice>` or anything else.

Required Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:envelope>
<soap:body>
<Order>
    <data1>
        <test>1</test>
        <test2>2</test2>
        <test3>3</test3>
    </data1>
</Order>
</soap:body>
</soap:envelope>
```

With the following XSLT, I need to know which node is coming in (Order or invoice) in order to match the pattern - but can this be a generic one?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
<!-- I do not want to specify the node here -->
    <xsl:template match="Order">
        <soap:envelope>
        <soap:body>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>              
        </soap:body>
        </soap:envelope>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: since the <root> is dynamic, try matching the root itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you show is not a well-formed XML document: you cannot use a prefix without binding it to a namespace. Your XSLT has the same flaw and cannot be used without producing an error (at least not with a conforming processor).

I am guessing you want to use:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <soap:envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <soap:body>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>              
        </soap:body>
    </soap:envelope>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to produce a valid [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap:body>
      <Order>
         <data1>
            <test>1</test>
            <test2>2</test2>
            <test3>3</test3>
         </data1>
      </Order>
   </soap:body>
</soap:envelope>
```

Comment: Thank you! yes I skipped the namespace in my original message but this works perfectly. Unable to upvote as of now, but have accepted the answer.

Comment: @michael : what is the difference in this case, if using namespace in stylesheet declaration instead of in the element itself? i,e., `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:soap="---"` vs `<soap:envelope xmlns:soap="---"`

Comment: @sspsujit There would be no difference in this case.

Answer (score -1):

you need to match the `root` for this.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <soap:envelope>
    <soap:body>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>              
    </soap:body>
    </soap:envelope>
</xsl:template>
```

test: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxWZS7L